# Where is cleavage site located?

Tags: biochemistry, restriction-enzymes

I feel a bit confused about cleaving!

Is cleavage site always located on the substrate or on the enzyme?

Comment: Hi. Your question seems incomplete. Please provide some context to your question. Also I really think this question can be googled and found easily their. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The cleavage site is always located on the substrate. It is specific sequence of bases (if we speak about DNA or RNA) or amino acids (proteins) that is recognized by the particular enzyme and cut.

Comment: Yes, and the site on the enzyme's side is called the "active site" or "catalytic site".